# Angular chosen isn't working properly

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I'm using chosen plun in for my selection options, but it's not working properly.
If I use like that

```
<select chosen
    data-placeholder="Pick one of these"
    disable-search="true">
<option value=""></option>
<option>This is fun</option>
<option>I like Chosen so much</option>
<option>I also like bunny rabbits</option>
```

just hard code for select option it's working,
 but in dynamic code with ng-options it doesn't show project items.

```
<select chosen
    data-placeholder="Pick one of these"
    disable-search="true"
    data-ng-model="state"
    ng-options="project for project in vm.projects">
```

[image]

How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two options that you can try :

**Option 1**
Use "project as project for project in vm.projects" provided 'project' is a string

```
<select chosen 
data-placeholder="Pick one of these" 
disable-search="true" 
data-ng-model="state" 
ng-options="project as project for project in vm.projects">
```

**Option 2**
You can also try using ng-repeat directive to repeat the options :

```
<select chosen data-placeholder="Pick one of these" disable-search="true" data-ng-model="state">
<option ng-repeat="project in vm.projects" value="{{project}}">{{project}}</option>
</select>
```

I hope this helps. Would have been better if you could provide the jsfiddle or plnkr for the code you have implemented.

Comment: I am not sure if my code is visible in the answer. I am trying to add the code but I am not able to see it. :(

Comment: unfortunately, the same result ((

Comment: I can't get my list of items, I have just get the result which I add a picture above

Comment: Are you sure you have 'vm.projects' available in your $scope ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that,  Maybe it'll help somebody, It's a incorrect using like that

`ng-options="project as project for project in vm.projects"`

It should be like that

`ng-options="project.Id as project.Name for project in vm.projects"`